# Apache Tiles View shows error on the 1st call

Tags: spring, apache-tiles

In my spring mvc project, the login page (or any other page) is generating a null pointer exception for the 1st call after tomcat starts. Any subsequent calls are working as expected. The controller end points that are returning JSON are working fine. Only the views constructed by Tiles are showing this problem. Any Idea? Here is the stack trace:

```
2014-04-29 08:51:47,013 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1525) - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'login'
2014-04-29 08:51:47,025 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (Digester.java:794) - Digester.getParser: 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.setSchema(SAXParserFactory.java:419)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getFactory(Digester.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getParser(Digester.java:791)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:1068)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1916)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.read(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:329)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURL(BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:276)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:251)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadParentDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:58)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:239)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadParentDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:58)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:239)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:222)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.checkAndloadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:204)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:154)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:123)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:54)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.getDefinition(UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.checkResource(TilesView.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:438)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:241)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.getCandidateViews(ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.java:356)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.resolveViewName(ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1239)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.mwired.grid.apps.web.filters.NoSlashUrlFilter.doFilter(NoSlashUrlFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.yammer.metrics.web.WebappMetricsFilter.doFilter(WebappMetricsFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2014-04-29 08:51:47,026 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (FrameworkServlet.java:959) - Could not complete request
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:1068)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1916)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.read(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:329)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURL(BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:276)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:251)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadParentDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:58)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:239)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadParentDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:58)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:239)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:222)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.checkAndloadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:204)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:154)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:123)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:54)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.getDefinition(UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.checkResource(TilesView.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:438)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:241)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.getCandidateViews(ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.java:356)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.resolveViewName(ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1239)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.mwired.grid.apps.web.filters.NoSlashUrlFilter.doFilter(NoSlashUrlFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.yammer.metrics.web.WebappMetricsFilter.doFilter(WebappMetricsFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2014-04-29 08:51:47,028 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:269) - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2014-04-29 08:51:47,029 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:97) - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2014-04-29 08:51:47,033 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (DispatcherServlet.java:823) - DispatcherServlet with name 'web-irm' processing GET request for [/web-irm/uncaughtException]
2014-04-29 08:51:47,034 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:220) - Looking up handler method for path /uncaughtException
2014-04-29 08:51:47,044 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:230) - Did not find handler method for [/uncaughtException]
2014-04-29 08:51:47,045 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (FlowHandlerMapping.java:114) - No flow mapping found for request with URI '/web-irm/uncaughtException'
2014-04-29 08:51:47,045 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:124) - Mapping [/uncaughtException] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController@28f4dfe9] and 1 interceptor
2014-04-29 08:51:47,045 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (DispatcherServlet.java:912) - Last-Modified value for [/web-irm/uncaughtException] is: -1
2014-04-29 08:51:47,045 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (WebContentInterceptor.java:145) - Looking up cache seconds for [/uncaughtException]
2014-04-29 08:51:47,045 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (WebContentInterceptor.java:157) - Applying default cache seconds to [/uncaughtException]
2014-04-29 08:51:47,046 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] (ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.java:320) - Requested media types are [] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
```

Comment: using tiles1 or tiles2?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that. Its tiles2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be using an old version of one of these jars in your project: xerces, xalan, jaxp api, crimson. Update it and try.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I do not include any of those in my pom. But I do see the  xerces, xalan jars in the deployed version in tomcat. Any idea how I can update them?

Comment: Updated my answer. Remove the old referenced and use this in your pom and check.

Comment: yea, updating the xerces dependency fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Updated this dependency on project,  and it Got worked